# Is there a function that helps populate meta data from an elementor form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a function that allows users to create an account from an elementor form I built but I need it to create and save the meta data to the user's profile after the account is created. The two meta fields that need to be created are: Date of Birth, Dog's Date of Birth, and Additional Comments.

Please also remember this form is built with elementor page builder on the front end and the php scripts installed on the functions.php file.

Here is the php code currently written.

```
// Custom Registration Form Code

add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user' , 10, 2 );
function thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user($record,$ajax_handler)
{
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
    //Check that the form is the "create new user form" if not - stop and return;
    if ('Create New User' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();
    $username=$form_data['Username']; //Get the value of the input with the label "User Name"
    $password = $form_data['Password']; //Get the value of the input with the label "Password"
    $email=$form_data['Email'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Email"
    $user = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email); // Create a new user


    if (is_wp_error($user)){ // if there was an error creating a new user
        $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: ".$user->get_error_message());

 //add the message
        $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
        return;
    }

    $first_name=$form_data["First Name"]; //Get the value of the input with the label "First Name"
    $last_name=$form_data["Last Name"]; //Get the value of the input with the label "Last Name"
    $user_phone=$form_data['Phone Number'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Phone Number"
    $more_notes=$form_data['Anything Else?'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Anything Else?"
    wp_update_user(array("ID"=>$user,"first_name"=>$first_name,"last_name"=>$last_name,"user_phone"=>$user_phone,"form_fields[dog_dob]"=>$more_notes)); // Update the user with the first name and last name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create new elementor form fields and give names to these fields like
[shown in the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZjBe.png)

Then you can access the field via field_id.

I have added a field named College Name and given the id as school.

To access the field in backend:

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user' , 10, 2 );
function thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user($record,$ajax_handler)
{
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $school_name = $raw_fields['school'];

    //process the data here
}
```